# How can I parse this datetime string?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

I can't figure it out, where did I go wrong?

I got the following datetime string, and need to parse it to datetime:

```
string timestr = "1/20/2014 12:05:16 AM"
```

And I trying to parse it like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact( timestr,
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                     null);
```

When trying to do this it returns

> "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Any tip?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for `01` to `12`

Use [`M`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) instead which is for `1` to `12`.

```
string timestr = "1/20/2014 12:05:16 AM";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(timestr,
                               "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
1/20/2014 12:05:16 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/egvIb5)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Also be careful about your hour formatting. [`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for `01` to `12`, [`HH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) is for `00` to `23`. If your hour will be `13`, `14` or `15` etc.. `hh` format will fail.

And since you using `null` as a `IFormatProvider` in your `DateTime.ParseExact` method, that means it uses `CurrentCulture` by default. And if it's [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is not `/`, your method throws `FormatException` *even* your string and format matches exactly because [`"/"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time formats like; *replace me current culture's or suplied culture date separator*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
 DateTime returnedDate = new DateTime();
 DateTime.TryParse(timestr, out returnedDate);
```

Comment: If OP's `CurrentCulture` doesn't accept `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` as a standard date and time pattern, your `DateTime.TryParse` returns `false` and your `returnedDate` will be `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

`M`-The month, from 1 through 12.

The "M" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from 1 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13 months). A single-digit month is formatted without a leading zero.

```
DateTime.ParseExact( timestr,"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

PLease try

```
string timestr = "1/20/2014 12:05:16 AM";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(timestr, out dt);
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, please explain to the user what the code does so they can learn from it, as is the reason they have come to stackoverflow

Comment: You don't _have to_ initialize `out parameter` by the way. `DateTime dt;` will be enough.

Comment: If OP's `CurrentCulture` doesn't accept `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` as a standard date and time pattern, your `DateTime.TryParse` returns `false` and your `dt` will be `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
this.RequestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.DcmCreateDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```